# Open file in Visual Studio's split window which is already open in another window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, vsvim

using Visual Studio 2019 Community here.

I have two windows split vertically (that is to say, a window on the left and one on the right) and I have a bunch of .h files open in my left window.

If I'm currently in the right-hand window, and use ctrl+shift+t (or ctrl+tab) to select a file which is already in a tab on the left window, it will open that tab in the left window and re-focus my cursor to the left window.

This sucks.

Is there a shortcut to either:
a) Open that file again but in the right window which I'm currently focused on, or
b) Move a currently-focused tab on the left window over to the right window?

I largely try to avoid using my mouse when I'm programming, so I'm also using VsVim if that helps or makes a difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are options for you to assign your own keyboard bindings.

Tools > Options > Environment - Keyboard

Assign shortcuts to Window.MoveToNextTabGroup and Window.MoveToPreviousTabGroup.